# Download contents of webpage, including external assets, with grunt

Tags: javascript, html, gruntjs, wget

I want to be able to run a grunt task in a directory of my site and be able to output the external CSS and JS (from CDN) directly in a new .html page. Basically, I want to quarantine the page from my other includes so I can move the file around or host it somewhere else. Is there a grunt task for this? Or will I have to WGET all the files and combine them manually or through a secondary grunt task?

Comment: You seem to be confusing `grunt` to be something similar/equivalent to `wget`. `Grunt` is a **task runner** and `wget` is a **task**. If you don't use `grunt`, you will need another task runner. If you dont use `wget`, you'll need another task that fetches files.

Comment: @tcooc ah yea, I was looking up https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-wget so go and grab the external assets.